# How to access VS code deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

How can I access all the files that are deployed from Visual Studio into Azure? I am creating a bot using bot framework which I then publish. But, when I go to review the code online I can't see all the files via the App Service Editor/Kudu/etc. The can't locate the files navigating the site directory.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Applications do not generally have the source code included when published.  Web Site projects, on the other hand do.  More information can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1

If you want to include the source code during the publish process, this can be done with a Post Deploy Script:

In the .csproj:

```
  <Import Project="PostDeployScripts\IncludeSources.targets" Condition="Exists('PostDeployScripts\IncludeSources.targets')" />
```

IncludeSources.targets:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CoreCompileDependsOn>$(CoreCompileDependsOn);IncludeSource</CoreCompileDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <Target Name="IncludeSource">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="**\*.cs" />
      <Content Include="**\*.csproj" />
      <Content Include="PostDeployScripts\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can enter the site's **[`"Kudu"`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/)** dashboard, using the url format

`http://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net`

This will give you a web-based dashboard, including a debug console (web-based) where you can explore your various directories

or

In Visual Studio, in the window **`"Server Explorer"`** you click and connect on "Azure".

**`=> App Service=> Your site name => Files`**

Here you see all your files and you can edit them directly in Visual Studio.

Comment: the issue isn't accessing where the files would be located. It's that not all files are visible despite the app still working. I need to know if there is a way to get all the files to show after deploying. I'll edit my question to reflect that. Thanks.